# Tabela de time com 8 variáveis

Tags: c#

Tenho uma questão meio difícil, tenho 8 times em uma tabela, já simulei os resultados porém preciso atualizar a tabela utilizando os pontos, para eu saber a quantidade de pontos de cada time eu escrevi o seguinte código:

```
        public void AtualizarTabela()
        {
        int TimePontos1 = Time1Vitoria * 3 + Time1Empate * 1;
        int TimePontos2 = Time2Vitoria * 3 + Time2Empate * 1;
        int TimePontos3 = Time3Vitoria * 3 + Time3Empate * 1;
        int TimePontos4 = Time4Vitoria * 3 + Time4Empate * 1;
        int TimePontos5 = Time5Vitoria * 3 + Time5Empate * 1;
        int TimePontos6 = Time6Vitoria * 3 + Time6Empate * 1;
        int TimePontos7 = Time7Vitoria * 3 + Time7Empate * 1;
        int TimePontos8 = Time8Vitoria * 3 + Time8Empate * 1;
        }
```

Como posso fazer essas variaveis de TimesPontos ficarem em ordem decrescente para depois eu atualizar a tabela? Tendo em vista que preciso retornar depois cada variável de pontos em uma label.

Comment: Não é mais fácil você utilizar um array para isso?

Comment: Já tentei usar o array mas como faço pra mim tirar da list na ordem e colocar nas labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria o seguinte:

```
public struct Estatistica
{
    public int Pontos { 
        get { return Vitorias * 3 + Empates; } 
    }

    public short Vitorias;
    public short Empates;
}

public void AtualizarTabela()
{
    Dictionary<string, Estatistica> times = new Dictionary<string, Estatistica>();
    time["Time 1"] = new Estatistica() { Vitorias = Time1Vitoria, Empates = Time1Empate };
    time["Time 2"] = new Estatistica() { Vitorias = Time2Vitoria, Empates = Time2Empate };
    time["Time 3"] = new Estatistica() { Vitorias = Time3Vitoria, Empates = Time3Empate };
    time["Time 4"] = new Estatistica() { Vitorias = Time4Vitoria, Empates = Time4Empate };
    time["Time 5"] = new Estatistica() { Vitorias = Time5Vitoria, Empates = Time5Empate };
    time["Time 6"] = new Estatistica() { Vitorias = Time6Vitoria, Empates = Time6Empate };
    time["Time 7"] = new Estatistica() { Vitorias = Time7Vitoria, Empates = Time7Empate };
    time["Time 8"] = new Estatistica() { Vitorias = Time8Vitoria, Empates = Time8Empate };
}
```

Ordenando decrescente:

```
    using System.Linq;

    foreach (var time in times.OrderByDescending(t => t.Value.Pontos)) 
    {
        // Escreva o que você precisa aqui. O nome do time está em `time.Key`.
        // O resto das informações está em `time.Value`.
        Console.WriteLine(time.Key);
    }
```

[Veja um exemplo aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e2eZVz).

---

Se for Web Forms, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label[] labels = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label[] {
    lblTime1LugarPontos,
    lblTime2LugarPontos,
    lblTime3LugarPontos,
    lblTime4LugarPontos,
    lblTime5LugarPontos,
    lblTime6LugarPontos,
    lblTime7LugarPontos,
    lblTime8LugarPontos
};
```

Windows Forms:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Label[] labels = new System.Windows.Forms.Label[] {
    lblTime1LugarPontos,
    lblTime2LugarPontos,
    lblTime3LugarPontos,
    lblTime4LugarPontos,
    lblTime5LugarPontos,
    lblTime6LugarPontos,
    lblTime7LugarPontos,
    lblTime8LugarPontos
};
```

O laço, então, fica assim:

```
    foreach (var infoTime in times.OrderByDescending(t => t.Value.Pontos).Select((time, i) => new { Time = time, i = i })) 
    {
        // labels[infoTime.i].Text = infoTime.Time.Key;
        labels[infoTime.i].Text = infoTime.Time.Value.Pontos;
    }
```

Comment: Só uma dúvida, como faço pra pegar o valor do time que ficou em 1° e coloca-lo em uma label.text agora?

Comment: Veja minha edição, se não ficou dúvida.

Comment: Olha ficou meio confusa, eu preciso retornar em ordem decrescente nas variáveis seguintes: lblTime1LugarPontos, lblTime2LugarPontos, lblTime3LugarPontos, lblTime4LugarPontos, lblTime5LugarPontos, lblTime6LugarPontos, lblTime6LugarPontos, lblTime7LugarPontos, lblTime8LugarPontos.

Comment: Ah, sim. Veja novamente.

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro: Cannot initialize type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Foi mal, jovem. É o sono. O correto é `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label[] labels = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label[] { ... };`. Já editei de novo.

Comment: Só uma ultima duvida, onde eu aplico o laço?

Comment: É uma boa pergunta. Você tem um botão de calcular nisso aí? Ou um evento que dispara esse cálculo? Se sim, o laço vai nele.

Comment: Eu tenho uma tabela feita com labels e paineis, (img: http://prntscr.com/f8q6x4) o botão jogar ativa um timer que atualiza a rodada e define os valores de vitória/derrota/empate dos times, preciso fazer os valores de pontos se organizarem pra mim usar como base para atualizar nome dos times - icons - labels

Comment: Pode ser no botão Jogar, então. Repare que já deixei a estrutura pronta pra você ter toda a lógica para a rodada.

Comment: Quando eu joguei no botão, o times.Order... diz que não existe no contexto.

Comment: Adicionou `using System.Linq;`, como te falei na resposta?

Comment: Sim já está em uso

Comment: Vai precisar refatorar um pouco. `times`, ou seja, `Dictionary<string, Estatistica> times = new Dictionary<string, Estatistica>();`, está em `AtualizarTabela()`. `times`, portanto, tem que ser declarada globalmente no Form.

Comment: Agora diz que labels não existem no contexto e "Time" não pode ser aceito como primeiro argumento do tipo "AnonymousType#1"

Comment: Melhor abrir outra pergunta. Não consigo ler sua tela.

Comment: Segue uma imagem. http://prntscr.com/f8qbua

Comment: Jovem, se `times` é global, `labels` também é. E é `infoTime.time.Value.Pontos`. O `time` é minúsculo porque o `.Select()` definiu minúsculo. Se você quer usar `Time`, maiúsculo, troque pra `.Select((time, i) => new { Time = time, i = i }))`.